# Spring 5 - How to provide static resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources, spring-webflux

I am trying provide static resources in my web application and I tried:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
WebMvcConfigurerAdapter configurer(){
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**").
                      addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        }
    };
}
```

BUT WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated in Spring 5. How can I access the static resources now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Spring 5 - Static Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-static-resources)

From the documentation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/public", "classpath:/static/")
                        .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add from the answer of @alfcope above:

The same objective can be achieved by directly extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurationSupport.html)

It seems like extending WebMvcConfigurationSupport serves the purpose of @EnableWebMvc and allows selectively override any desired default implementation and in this case addResourceHandlers. So the example code can be

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/public", "classpath:/static/")
                        .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        }

}
```