# Spring 5: How to load static resources (css, js, images)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am upgrading a project from Spring 4 to spring 5 but loading static resources is not working.
I have my resources in 
    `src/main/resources/static/js`, 
    `src/main/resources/static/css` and 
    `src/main/resources/static/images`

I add a ResourceHandler in WebConfig as follows

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.job.controllers"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
    // more code here
}
```

My security configuration to allow access to the static resources is as follows

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   @Override 
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login**", "/static/**").permitAll()
   }
}
```

When i access `http://localhost:8080/static/css/file.css`

I get the error `405 Request method 'GET' not supported`

The problem seems not to be in the security config as it doesn't redirect me to the login page. If I try a none public URL like `http://localhost:8080/some-place/css/file.css` i get redirected to the login page.

The problem seems to be in the ResourceHandler.

My dependencies are:
    `spring-framework - 5.0.2.RELEASE and spring-security-5.0.0.RELEASE`

None of the answers in the other questions work for me.
[other-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567681/spring-5-how-to-provide-static-resources) 
Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567681/spring-5-how-to-provide-static-resources

Answer (score 0):

I realised that when I commented out the `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.job.controllers"})` line on `WebConfig` class, the static resources would load.

This meant that that the problem was in one of my controllers.

One controller method was mapped  `@RequestMapping(params = "settings/view", method = RequestMethod.POST)`

That mapping showed up as `INFO  Mapped "{[],methods=[POST],params=[settings/view]}" onto .....` in the startup logs

This was an incorrect mapping and it was stopping the static resources from loading.

When I corrected 'params' to 'value' like this => `@RequestMapping(value = "settings/view", method = RequestMethod.POST)` the static resources loaded.

Thanks