# How to serve dynamically created files with Java spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to build an app (with Spring boot) that will generate files (.js files), which have to be publicly available. 
These files (after being created) should be accessible by the link on my server and insertable into someone else's website (with a link).
Something similar to how 'jQuery' or 'Google Adwords' work (how they are connected with a html script tag).
So the problem i'm facing (or just a lack of knowledge) is how to create these files dynamically and make them accessible publicly.

The idea in general is: 1 user has 1 folder (inside of resources/files folder for example) (let's name it folder1232). Inside this folder his specific js files are generated (for example 111.js). So i want him to be able to access his file by requesting app.com/files/folder1232/111.js URL. What will be the way of doing it?
Please let me know if something is unclear.

I'm currently playing with resources folder to understand how it works generally. What I see is that files are somehow mapped on startup (so for example if I create a new folder with a file in runtime, it's not accessible until I restart the app).
I also tried to use WebMvcConfigurer, but I think I'm missing something basic.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/files/")
                .setCachePeriod(3600)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
}
```

I expect to access newly created files (in runtime) from browser. 
Also would be perfect if i could be able to access newly created folders (in runtime) as well.
But atm I have to restart an app to access newly created files and folders.

UPDATE:
What i tried to do next, is to create a folder outside my java project.
Like this: /Users/%username%/Documents/fileFold
And changed my addResourceHandler function to:

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/Users/%username%/Documents/fileFold/")
                .setCachePeriod(0)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
    }
```

Now it works perfectly. Thanks everyone!
NOTE: Don't forget the last slash in your addResourceLocations function, mapping will not work without it (didnt work for me at least).

Comment: Do not mix files from your app with user data

Comment: This is near-the-edge to a duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567681/spring-5-how-to-provide-static-resources

Comment: You have to restart your app because the `resources` folder is part of your project, which is built before you start it. This is **not** the place for dynamically generated files (as @Jens pointed out), especially not files generated by user actions. You should use a dedicated folder outside of your project structure. The default in Spring Boot is (it think) the current working directory of your app, so if you `new File("userFiles/folder1232").mkdirs()` (or something like that), this folder will be created in the current working dir.

Comment: You have to change your  approach:1.  with real files you should use nginx or apache wth cache disabled (Spring boot is not designed to be a static file server) , 2. but if your files are generated via java, serve them as normal ressources, not with resourceHandler.

Comment: @pdem If I do registry.setCachePeriod(0) in my WebMvcConfigurer inheritor, wouldn't it be enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what worked for me specifically:
I created a folder to store files OUTSIDE the project. 
e.g. /Users/%username%/Documents/fileFold

And changed my addResourceHandlers function to

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/files/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/Users/%username%/Documents/fileFold/")
                .setCachePeriod(0)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
```

NOTE: Don't forget the last slash in your addResourceLocations function, mapping will not work without it (didnt work for me at least).

Answer (score 0):

First,
understand the problem that you are actually attempting to solve.
Don't just jump to the "I want this solution".

The problem you are attempting to solve appears to be this:

1. My application will "create" some copy (copy is the generic term for text, which includes your .js files).
2. Said copy will be publicly addressable via some unique identifier.

Neither of the above requirements demands that you create files anywhere.

One simple solution is:
In the solution below, "row" can be either exactly one row or an ordered collection of 1 or more rows.

1. Create a row in a table that comprise the "copy" to be served.
2. Use a unique value to identify the row.
3. [Optional] Create a table to translate between a human-readable name (aka a file name) for the row and the unique identifier for said row.
4. Create a REST service to fetch a row by human-readable name.